# How to get a right value in the result? (calculator js)

Tags: javascript

Good day. I have a mistake in the logic of storing the numbers, but i can't figure out why. In result, i need to have the correct answer like "1+1 = 2", instead i have "1+1 = 1".
And one more question is how to store a lot of operations, like "2 + 2 / 4 * 1"?

I will be very appreciate for your help.

p.s. https://codepen.io/Dmxvil/pen/MWyBqOz (you can see the calculator here with html)

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calc]'),
    operators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operator]'),
    prev = document.querySelector('.prev-result'),
    current = document.querySelector('.current-number'),
    //resetBtn = document.querySelector('.operator-btn-reset'),
    resultBtn = document.querySelector('[data-result]');

let prevData = [];
let currentData = [];
let operation,
computation;

    numbers.forEach((number => {
        number.addEventListener('click', () => {
            current.innerHTML = number.innerText;
            currentData.push(number.dataset.calc);
            current.innerHTML = currentData.join('');
        });
    }));


function updateDisplay(){
        prev.innerHTML = currentData.join('');
        prevData = prev.innerHTML;
        currentData.splice(0, 100);
        current.innerHTML = '';
}


function chooseOperator() {
    operators.forEach(operator => {
        operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
            operation = operator.innerText;
            switch (operator.innerText) {
                case '+':
                    console.log(operation);
                    computation = prevData + currentData;
                    console.log(computation);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    console.log(operation);
                    computation = prevData - currentData;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    console.log(operation);
                    computation = prevData * currentData;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    console.log(operation);
                    computation = prevData / currentData;
                    break;
            }

            updateDisplay();
        });
    });
}

chooseOperator();

function result(){
    prev.innerHTML = prevData + operation + currentData.join('');
    current.innerHTML = computation.toString();
}

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    result();
});
```

Comment: Good that you are learning JS. Can you add HTML code also, so your snippet will be working? It is interesting to look at working ("almost") example

Comment: JavaScript does not care about types of the variables. Sometimes it is good, but most of the time it is bad. For example you have variable: `let prevData = [];` (so it is array), but then `prevData = prev.innerHTML;` (oh, come on! you replace array with a string, so now array is lost). In that case: `prevData`  must be array or string? :)

Comment: @Anton i add a pen https://codepen.io/Dmxvil/pen/MWyBqOz , thank you. i think i need to save my array but transform it in string to show it in display?

Comment: You are about to write your own simple parser to execute strings like `2 + 2 / 4 * 1`. It might be tricky depending on the complexity of the expressions. Or alternatively have a look at `eval` function, which of course has its pros and cons as well - https://javascript.info/eval When is JavaScript's eval() not evil? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look. Without 'eval'. Maybe, not optimal in some ways, but at least it is working as expected. It means that `12 + 7 - 5 * 3` will be `42`.

I've added comments to the code, but you can ask if something is not clear.

Note: I also added two new labels - one to show the operator and another one to show the expression. Why? Because it is more beautiful for me. If you do not need them - just say. We can remove them.

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calc]'),
  operators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operator]:not([data-operator=AC])'),
  prev = document.getElementById('prev-result'),
  current = document.getElementById('current-number'),
  resultBtn = document.querySelector('[data-result]'),
  acButton = document.querySelector('[data-operator=AC]'),
  operatorLabel = document.getElementById('operator'),
  expression = document.getElementById('expression');

let firstNumber; // this is previous result
let secondNumber; // this is what we enter with keyboard

const setOperator = (x) => operatorLabel.innerHTML = x !== undefined ? x : '';
const getOperator = () => operatorLabel.innerHTML;

numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (firstNumber !== undefined && getOperator() == '') {
      // ignore previous result if we did not link it with operator
      firstNumber = undefined;
    }
    if (isNaN(parseInt(current.innerHTML))) current.innerHTML = '';
    current.innerHTML += button.innerText;
    secondNumber = parseInt(current.innerHTML);
  });
});

operators.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (secondNumber !== undefined) {
      if (firstNumber !== undefined) {
        // continue of expression
        const result = processResult();
        setOperator(button.innerText);
        firstNumber = result.result;
      } else {
        // we have no previous result
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = undefined;
        current.innerHTML = '';
        prev.innerHTML = firstNumber;
        setOperator(button.innerText);
      }
    } else if (firstNumber !== undefined) {
      // we have previous result, but empty next number
      setOperator(button.innerText);
    }
  });
});

acButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  current.innerHTML = '';
  secondNumber = undefined;
  setOperator();
});

const getResult = () => {
  const operator = getOperator();
  if (firstNumber !== undefined && secondNumber !== undefined && operator != '') {
    const str = String(firstNumber) + operator + secondNumber;
    let result = {
      result: NaN,
      str
    };
    if (operator == '+') result.result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    if (operator == '-') result.result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    if (operator == '/') result.result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    if (operator == '*') result.result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    return result;
  }
}

const processResult = () => {
  const result = getResult();
  if (result !== undefined) {
    if (isNaN(result.result)) {
      current.innerHTML = 'Error';
      setOperator();
      prev.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
      prev.innerHTML = result.result;
      firstNumber = result.result;
      current.innerHTML = '';
      secondNumber = undefined;
      setOperator();
    }
    expression.innerHTML = result.str + ' = ' + (isNaN(result.result) ? 'Undefined' : result.result);
  }
  return result;
}

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  processResult();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.calculator .calculator-grid {
  width: 300px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons {
  display: grid;
  width: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons button:active {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input:active {
  border: none;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input .prev-result {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input .current-number {
  height: 60px;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons .operator-btn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons .operator-btn:active {
  background-color: aqua;
}

div.prev-container {
  position: relative;
}

div.operator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: -10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#expression {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  top: -16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="calculator__input">
      <div class="calc-input">
        <div class="prev-container">
          <div id="expression"></div>
          <div class="prev-result" id="prev-result"></div>
          <div class="operator" id="operator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="current-number" id="current-number"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator__buttons">
      <button data-calc="7">7</button>
      <button data-calc="8">8</button>
      <button data-calc="9">9</button>
      <button data-operator="-" class="operator-btn-minus operator-btn">-</button>
      <button data-calc="4">4</button>
      <button data-calc="5">5</button>
      <button data-calc="6">6</button>
      <button data-operator="+" class="operator-btn-plus operator-btn">+</button>
      <button data-calc="3">3</button>
      <button data-calc="2">2</button>
      <button data-calc="1">1</button>
      <button data-operator="*" class="operator-btn operator-btn-multiply">*</button>
      <button data-calc="0">0</button>
      <button data-operator="AC" class="operator-btn operator-btn-reset">AC</button>
      <button data-result="=" class="operator-btn operator-btn-result">=</button>
      <button data-operator="/" class="operator-btn operator-btn-divide">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you i'm exploring your code and try to change mine. here what i have done yesterday by myself https://codepen.io/Dmxvil/pen/MWyBqOz , only need to do smth with inputs because it shows only one number. what can you say about this solution?

Comment: @vol4ikeurope just a quick look. 1) `takePrevValue` name of the function is not correct. It does not take value, it just adds event listeners, 2) same for `clear` and `chooseOperator`, `takeCurrentValue`, 3) `takePrevValue` and `takeCurrentValue` append duplicate event, you should combine this 2 event listeners to one

Comment: @vol4ikeurope this line `if (prevData === '' && currentData === '')` blocks every input beyond one symbol

Comment: @vol4ikeurope `currentData.toString()` - in your code `currentData` is always the string. No need to convert it again, right? Same for `num.toString()`, because `num` is already a string

Comment: i replaced takePrevValue and takeCurrentValue by a single function appendNum, clear by reset, chooseOperator by getOperator and also deleted unnecessary converts. thank you for review. trying to figure out what is the problem with conditions of input

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? I used `eval`.

```js
const numbersAndOperators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calc]'),
  prev = document.getElementById('prev-result'),
  current = document.getElementById('current-number'),
  resultBtn = document.querySelector('[data-result]'),
  acButton = document.querySelector('[data-operator=AC]');

numbersAndOperators.forEach((button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current.innerHTML += button.innerText;
  });
}));

acButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  current.innerHTML = '';
});

function result() {
  try {
    let res = eval(current.innerHTML);
    prev.innerHTML = current.innerHTML + ' = ' + (isNaN(res) ? 'Undefined' : res);
    current.innerHTML = '';
  } catch (e) {
    prev.innerHTML = e.message;
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', result);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.calculator .calculator-grid {
  width: 300px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons {
  display: grid;
  width: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons button:active {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input:active {
  border: none;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input .prev-result {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.calculator .calculator__input .calc-input .current-number {
  height: 60px;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons .operator-btn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

.calculator .calculator__buttons .operator-btn:active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<section class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="calculator__input">
      <div class="calc-input">
        <div class="prev-result" id="prev-result"></div>
        <div class="current-number" id="current-number"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculator__buttons">
      <button data-calc="7">7</button>
      <button data-calc="8">8</button>
      <button data-calc="9">9</button>
      <button data-operator="-" data-calc="-" class="operator-btn-minus operator-btn">-</button>
      <button data-calc="4">4</button>
      <button data-calc="5">5</button>
      <button data-calc="6">6</button>
      <button data-operator="+" data-calc="+" class="operator-btn-plus operator-btn">+</button>
      <button data-calc="3">3</button>
      <button data-calc="2">2</button>
      <button data-calc="1">1</button>
      <button data-operator="*" data-calc="*" class="operator-btn operator-btn-multiply">*</button>
      <button data-calc="0">0</button>
      <button data-operator="AC" class="operator-btn operator-btn-reset">AC</button>
      <button data-result="=" class="operator-btn operator-btn-result">=</button>
      <button data-operator="/" data-calc="/" class="operator-btn operator-btn-divide">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

P.S. As I use `eval`, so you can also add brackets `(` and `)` here.
For math operations like `sqrt` or `log` we need some other technique...

Comment: Thank you! Yes it's works like i need,  but i'm trying to avoid eval(), so i need to keep switch or write a separate functions

Comment: @vol4ikeurope may I ask you why do you avoid eval?

Comment: it's my task in the course i'm studying ( https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/calculator )

Comment: @vol4ikeurope I'll look at your question later if no-one will answer before me =)

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your help